# Error: The app you are using is not responding. Please try again later

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-credits

I am using the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/build/) given here, first tried localhost as a callBack Url and then tried real IP, both time I got the error given in Question title. How can I resolve it? I am using PHP

Thanks

I am in Sandbox Mode

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an IP address of your personal computer which can not be reached, then it will not work.  You must have a public IP address in order for it to work.  The fact that you used "localhost" as a callback url means you are most likely doing this.

Comment: i have 2 separate apps added. I tried same code on remote machine with remote Call back URL and got the same error

Comment: OK I rechecked the URL, it was missing **hittp://** after adding that I am now getting this error _Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction. Please try again_